# 11 sided irregular shape that tessellates

Tags: tessellations

My friend was fiddling around on the triangle when he created an irregular heptagon with it not able to tessellate.

[image]

He then asked me if I could create an 11 sided irregular polygon that is able to tessellate by changing a side AB. He told me there was 3 and that you can make 2 more without necessarily using the side AB. I have absolutely no idea what they are. Can I please have some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For: "*create an 11 sided irregular polygon that is able to tessellate by changing a side AB*":

[image: Something I'd like to call projection]

[image: With Axis of Symmetry]

which then becomes:

[image: Tessellation shape]

where I just a projected a duplicate triangle, using the axis of symmetry between side `AB` (to be changed) and side `AC` (the side with tessellation to be matched with). And there you have your shape. There are more you can make, take this **example** as a **hint**.

For: "*you can make 2 more without necessarily using the side AB*":

Here's another **hint**:

[image: Second Axis of Symmetry]

Good Luck!

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean with the last hint. How does that affect the overall triangle? @Sniping Poodle

Comment: The last hint is the axis of symmetry for side `CB`, since that is the one you can change other than `AB`, relative to your question of: "_2 more without necessarily using the side AB_"

Comment: Do what I did in the answer above but this time for side `CB` instead of `AB`.